# Desire2Learn Valence API Accessing the Data Purge Tool?

Tags: php, api, desire2learn

Is it possible to access the Data Purge Tool from the Valence API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there are no APIs into the Data Purge system.

What kind of access to the data purge tool were you looking for?

Comment: The ability to run a batch process to purge course data was the plan.  We are looking for a way to delete a development shell after a certain period of time.